# Ruby Output Unicode Character

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, utf-8, ruby-1.8.7

I'm not a Ruby dev by trade, but am using Capistrano for PHP deployments. I'm trying to cleanup the output of my script and am trying to add a [unicode check mark](http://www.charbase.com/2713-unicode-check-mark) as discussed in [this blog](http://jondavidjohn.com/cleaning-up-capistrano-deployment-output/).

The problem is if I do:

```
checkmark = "\u2713"
puts checkmark
```

It outputs "\u2713" instead of ✓

I've googled around and I just can't find anywhere that discusses this.

TLDR: How do I `puts` or `print` the unicode checkmark U-2713?

**EDIT**

---

I am running Ruby 1.8.7 on my Mac (OSX Lion) so cannot use the `encode` method. My shell is Bash in iTerm2.

---

**UPDATE** [4/8/2019] Added reference image in case site ever goes down.

[image: Unicode Check Mark U+2713]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### In Ruby 1.9.x+

Use [`String#encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-encode):

```
checkmark = "\u2713"
puts checkmark.encode('utf-8')
```

prints

```
✓
```

### In Ruby 1.8.7

```
puts '\u2713'.gsub(/\\u[\da-f]{4}/i) { |m| [m[-4..-1].to_i(16)].pack('U') }
✓
```

Comment: I should have mentioned I have Ruby 1.8.7 and apparently the `encode` method isn't available until 1.9. How was it done prior to 1.9?

Comment: @cillosis, I added Ruby 1.8.7 compatible version. You should use `'\u2713'` or `"\\u2713"`, because `"\u2713" == "u2713"` in ruby 1.8.

Comment: Bam! I first tried your solution and it wasn't working. Then went to single quotes and it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: I was able to simply do something like `checkmark = "\u2713".encode('utf-8'); puts checkmark` and so the encoding was saved to the variable. This works for me in Ruby 2.2.2.

Comment: @sixty4bit, If you want to notify OP, mention OP or comment on the question. Otherwise, OP will not be notified.

Comment: checkmark = "\u2663"
puts checkmark.encode('utf-8') prints ♣ for me!

Comment: `"\u127968".encode("utf-8")` is giving me `ቹ68`. I was hoping for ``. Is there a Ruby way to print the upper ranges of Unicode?

Comment: @Lori, `"\u{1f3e0}"` (`'1f3e0' == 127968.to_s(16)`)

Answer (score 23):

In newer versions of Ruby, you don't need to enforce encoding. Here is an example with `2.1.2`:

```
2.1.2 :002 > "\u00BD"
 => "½"
```

Just make sure you use double quotes!

Comment: This comment about making sure to use double-quotes saved me -- I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out why this wasn't working!

Answer (score 18):

falsetru's answer is incorrect.

```
checkmark = "\u2713"
puts checkmark.encode('utf-8')
```

This transcodes the checkmark from the current system encoding to UTF-8 encoding.
(That works only on a system whose default is already UTF-8.)

The correct answer is:

```
puts checkmark.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

This modifies the string's encoding, without modifying any character sequence.

Answer (score 5):

As an additional note, if you want to print an emoji, you have to surround it with braces.

```
irb(main):001:0> "\u{1F600}"
=> ""
```

Comment: Nice but doesn't seem to work with string interpolation `a=1F600; puts "\u{#{a}}"`

Comment: @builder-7000 I found a way to do it: `a = '1F600'; puts a.to_i(16).chr('UTF-8')`. Outputs .

Answer (score 0):

Same goes as above in ERB, no forced encoding required, works perfectly, tested at Ruby 2.3.0

```
    <%= "\u00BD" %>
```

Much appreciation

Answer (score 0):

How we can print as is in newer version of ruby

checkmark = "\u2713"
puts checkmark

This should print AS IS \u2713

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).